Insert() method for a Red-Black Tree
I am trying to implement a Red-Black Tree with insert() method for a new node and if the node can either become the root node, left node of the root node or the right node of the root node. I keep running into error when i tried to run the code against my test code base.
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'right' for the current.right in the while loop under the insert method.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
class RBNode:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.red = False
        self.parent = None
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class RBTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nil = RBNode(None)
        self.nil.red = False
        self.nil.left = None
        self.nil.right = None
        self.root = self.nil

    def insert(self, val):
        new_node = RBNode(val)
        new_node.left = self.nil
        new_node.right = self.nil
        new_node.red = True

        parent = None
        current = self.root
        while current != self.nil:
            parent = current
            if new_node.val < current:
                current = current.left
            if new_node.val > current:
                current = current.right
            else:
                return
            
        new_node.parent = parent
        if parent == None:
            self.root = new_node.val
        else:
            if new_node.val < parent.val:
                parent.left = new_node.val
            elif new_node.val > parent.val:
                parent.right = new_node

